# How do create an or statement for the below code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to display a tick or X depending on whether a campaign is approved or rejected. At present I am able to do one at a time but how do I combine or add an or statement to this? Every attempt I have made ends in failure.

```
%td= campaign.status == "Approved" ?  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>'.html_safe : campaign.status
```

I assumed this would work but regrettably not:

```
%td= campaign.status == "Approved" ?  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>'.html_safe || campaign.status == "Rejected" ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-success"></span>'.html_safe
```

Comment: Replace your `||` with `:`

Comment: @Gerep then append another `: html text` clause to avoid syntax error.

Comment: @Gerep Sorry but could you clarify where you mean to add this? Just to clarify I want a glyphicon if status is Approved and a different glyphicon if status is Rejected.

Comment: Sure, try this: `%td= campaign.status == "Approved" ?  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>'.html_safe : campaign.status == "Rejected" ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-success"></span>'.html_safe : '<span class="SOME-ICON-TO-SHOW-UNEXPECTED-STATUS"></span>'.html_safe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ternary you don't have the `or` option, you can use only `?` and `:`

**Be careful because nesting ternary operations can result in code that's downright confusing and I don't see any advantages in doing that**

Instead of using `||` you should be using `:`, meaning `else`, [try it here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ruby_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMOUFmZzl3Rm5QT0U)

I'll break the code in lines for clarity:

```
%td=
campaign.status == "Approved"
? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>'.html_safe
: campaign.status == "Rejected"
? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-success"></span>'.html_safe
: '<span class="SOME-ICON-TO-SHOW-UNEXPECTED-STATUS"></span>'.html_safe
```

This code is the same as this:

```
if campaign.status == "Approved"
  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>'.html_safe
elsif campaign.status == "Rejected"
  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-success"></span>'.html_safe
else
  '<span class="SOME-ICON-TO-SHOW-UNEXPECTED-STATUS"></span>'.html_safe
end
```

I suggest you use a view helper for that purpose, will make your code cleaner:

`%td=campaign_status(compaign.status)`